# Formating change in Excel when refresh data source connectred with SQL Server

Tags: excel

I connected MS Excel with MS SQL Server and fetch data from DB and made a table. Some columns have been wrapping due to wide column length. But when I refresh data source then the formatting is changed to previous default format. How can I keep the format same as my expected?

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps.

1- Click on the table in which you are populating the data from the database

2- Click on the DATA tab

3- In Connections group, click on properties

4- Uncheck the option (Adjust column width)

5- Check mark the other two options i.e. (Preserve cell formatting and preserve column sort)

image link = https://ibb.co/jg6MQ4b

Hope this will help you